# iOS not loading JavaScript file with Class declaration

Tags: javascript, html, ios, cross-browser, device

In my javascript file I have the following:

```
alert('loaded JS file');
class myClass{
    constuctor(value){
        this.value = value;
    }
    myfunc(){
        //some method
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

In my html file I have the following:

```
<script src="/myJSFile"></script>
<script>
    let someVal = 5;
    let myInstance = new myClass(someval);
</script>
```

This works fine on all computers and some mobile devices, but it does not work on all mobile devices. My iPhone6 running iOS 10 runs into an error where the `alert('loaded JS file')` is never executed and thus it has the error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: myClass`. However, if I remove the code creating the class from the javascript file, then the alert is triggered on mobile. So my guess is that class declaration is not supported for some reason on some mobiles, but really I am not sure because I would think that is standard across all browsers/devices.

**Why would the javascript file not load *only* on some mobile devices?**

Comment: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

Answer (score 0):

`class` was only added in ES2015, and isn't universally supported, particularly not on legacy versions of mobile operating systems. But even IE11 on desktops, for instance, doesn't support `class`. Details: https://caniuse.com/#feat=es6-class

If you want to use `class` on older devices, you'll need to *transpile* to ES5 code. ([Babel](https://babeljs.io) is one tool for doing that.)

(Side note: You have a typo in your constructor, you're missing the letter `r` in the name.)

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense. Thank you, very helpful!

Comment: Something as basic as `class` you'd really expect to be supported in older versions. It works perfect now. Again, much appreciated the advice.

Comment: @James - Well, when those older versions were written, it didn't exist, so... :-) (IE11 -- for example -- was released in October 2013. ES2015 was published in June 2015, and then of course implementations had to update to support it [it's a bit different now, a feature doesn't officially land in the spec until at least two implementations are shipping with it, but that wasn't true for ES2015]. A lot of Android users are still using versions of Android from before 2015.)